# Ember.js Default select text Not displaying in Ember.Select in '1.0.pre';

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember.js '1.0.pre' release.

I am trying to use :

```
{{view Ember.Select prompt="Select one option..."}}
```

Its rendering as :

```
<select id="ember2531" class="ember-view ember-select"> 
Select one option... 
<script id="metamorph-41-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
<script id="metamorph-41-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> </select>
```

I dont see
    <option>Select one option...</option> 
being rendered.

Is this a bug in Ember.js '1.0.pre' release ?

Comment: To be clear, you are not using the newest Ember (1.0.0-RC1) available on [the website](http://emberjs.com/)? You should try upgrading first.

Comment: Works in this JSBin using 1.0.0.RC1: http://jsbin.com/ixupad/219/edit